# Accessing image tag id in javascript when it is placed inside asp server control, Error:The server tag is not well defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have code as shown below

```
 <asp:TemplateField FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="Column1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="Column1" style="visibility:<%# SetEditImagesVisibility()%>;">
                    <img src="" id="iEdit"  alt="Edit" class='btntransparent' onclick="EditQC('<%#Eval("ID") %>')" />
                    <img src="" id="iDelete" alt="Delete" class='btntransparent'  onclick="DeleteQ('<%#Eval("ID") %>')" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div style="visibility:<%# SetAddImagesVisibility()%>;">
                    <img src="" alt="Add" class='btntransparent' id="iPlus" runat="server" onclick="AddTestingID()" />
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here i need to access img tag id in javascript(iEdit and iDelete) but am getting error as
The Server tag is not well defined
javascript code is shown below

```
  document.getElementsById('iEdit').src = HostedPath + 'pics/edit.gif';
  document.getElementsById('iDelete').src = HostedPath + 'pics/edit.gif';
```

Any one please help me out in fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `onclick` attributes like this:

```
<img src="" id="iEdit" alt="Edit" class='btntransparent' onclick='<%# "EditQC(" + Eval("ID").ToString() + ")" %>' />
<img src="" id="iDelete" alt="Delete" class='btntransparent'  onclick='<%# "DeleteQ(" + Eval("ID").ToString() + ")" %>' />
```

The `Eval` method must wrap the entire attribute, instead the tag will really be misformed.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I tried your code but still am unable to get the image src reference in javascript as i need to put image reference path in javascript only(On Requirement).

Comment: Its working fine now , "ID" was not getting in aspx page which was set in property window just i changed and i set ID in codefile its working now. Thanks for your help , I have replaced with your code only